# Stuck in difference selection mode

Tags: modeling, interface

I´m new to this version of Blender and stuck in what i figured out is difference selection method. However the submenu I found is not displayed and I have not found a shortcut to circle through the options. Any idea where to enable this menu? 
Thanks! 
[image: Where do I find this menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess these function have now been transformed into icons, either in the *N* menu > *Tool*, or in the *Properties* panel > *Active Tool* (first tab)

[image]